# What is the Difference between Reactive Extensions and Message Queue?

Tags: c#, architecture, .net, message-queue, reactive

I am trying to understand the difference between Reactive Extensions and Message Queue? Are they competing frameworks? Can they be used in conjuction? Started programming, and trying to understand this.

Reactive Extensions: " The Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style query operators."

Message Queue: "A message queue is a queue of messages sent between applications. It includes a sequence of work objects that are waiting to be processed. "

Comment: They are two completely different things. What makes you think they are similar?

Comment: A "message queue" generically is just a list of data designed to induce behaviour in a different part of a system (maybe synchronously or not), where the elements in the list are processed in FIFO order, and typically by a part of the system that is not closely coupled to the parts which add the elements into the queue. Reactive Extensions is a set of tools designed for manipulating the temporal aspects of data flows in a system - whereas a lot of data manipulation involves specifying *what* processing occurs, Rx is designed to alter *when* processing occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> Are they competing frameworks?

No, these are not competing and they are very different ideas.

RX is a library that is frequently used in applications that require real-time processing over a stream of events. RX gives you a library of functions to perform this with ease.

Message Queue (MQ) is more of an architecture component than a library. MQs are used to decouple event-producing logic and event-consuming logic. Example: on a user sign up page, you may want to perform a series of actions; one of it is sending of a welcome email to user. You may decide that you do not want the user to wait too long on the loading screen, therefore you use an MQ to simply trigger a “send welcome email” event to be processed later.

> Can they be used in conjuction?

Yes. For example, in a file processing application -

1) Use RX to process a stream of CSV records

2) You can combine records, transform, etc

3) Take the final result and put it into a queue, then move on to next batch of CSV records

4) Meanwhile, a queue consumer reads that result above and performs an upload of the result to a remote file server

Answer (score 0):

> A "message queue" generically is just a list of data designed to
>   induce behaviour in a different part of a system (maybe synchronously
>   or not), where the elements in the list are processed in FIFO order,
>   and typically by a part of the system that is not closely coupled to
>   the parts which add the elements into the queue. Reactive Extensions
>   is a set of tools designed for manipulating the temporal aspects of
>   data flows in a system - whereas a lot of data manipulation involves
>   specifying what processing occurs, Rx is designed to alter when
>   processing occurs.

-- [Steve](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/292095/steve) [Oct 8 '19 at 9:10](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/399448/what-is-the-difference-between-reactive-extensions-and-message-queue#comment878476_399448)